# Macro that searches with the name a cell from a selection of items from a list and finds it in another sheet

Tags: excel, windows, vba, list, button

I am new in VBA and I want to write a program that when I manually select 1 or more items from a list the code searches with the name of the item and picks it from another sheet, copies the whole row and pastes it in a 3rd sheet. Is that possible? Preferably with a click of a button the selection is made. Thanks a lot!

Comment: A similar result can also be achieved without any VBA at all using VLOOKUPS and a pivot table.

Comment: Hi! i am writting very little on my own but i am learning! This however was a lot out of my reach for the moment that is why i seek help. Thanks a lot for the help. :D

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example.

```
Sub FindAndMove()
Dim Finder As Range
Dim TheItem As Variant
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Selection.CountLarge = 1 And Not Intersect(Selection, .Range("A2:A11")) Is Nothing Then
        TheItem = Selection.Value
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please select an item from the list")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set Finder = .Range("A:A").Find(TheItem, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Finder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Item not found!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    With Sheets("Sheet3")
        Finder.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & .UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge + 1)
        .Select 'Optional - show sheet 3
    End With
End With
End Sub
```

Walking through the code:

When they click the button, if they only select 1 cell that's in our list.

Get the value of the item they selected

On `Sheet2` - go find that value in column `A`

If you find it, copy the entire row to the end of `Sheet3`

You can modify the code by changing the sheet names in `Sheet("Sheet1")` to whatever you want.

You can also change the list range by changing `.Range("A2:A11")`

You can change the range to search by changing `.Range("A:A")`

**Sheet 1:**

[image: Sheet1]

**Sheet 2:**

[image: Sheet2]

**Sheet 3:** (after we select item 3 and click Find and Move)

[image: Sheet 3]

**Error Handling:**

[image: Error Handling 1]

[image: Error Handling 2]

**Edit:**

Code to find multiple occurrences using `FindNext`

```
Sub FindAndMove()
Dim Finder As Range
Dim FirstAddress As Variant
Dim TheItem As Variant
With Sheets("Sheet1")
    If Selection.CountLarge = 1 And Not Intersect(Selection, .Range("A2:A11")) Is Nothing Then
        TheItem = Selection.Value
    Else
        MsgBox ("Please select an item from the list")
        Exit Sub
    End If
End With
With Sheets("Sheet2")
    Set Finder = .Range("A:A").Find(TheItem, LookAt:=xlWhole)
    If Finder Is Nothing Then
        MsgBox ("Item not found!")
        Exit Sub
    End If
    FirstAddress = Finder.Address
    Do
        With Sheets("Sheet3")
            Finder.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & .UsedRange.Rows.CountLarge + 1)
        End With
        Set Finder = .Range("A:A").FindNext(Finder)
    Loop While Not Finder Is Nothing And Finder.Address <> FirstAddress
End With
Sheets("Sheet3").Select 'Optional - Select Sheet3 After.
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! This was extremely helpful! :D

Comment: Hi again,i ve tried to modify it with FindNext. None of my attemts works.Here is my latest unsuccessful mod and hope for your help.      Set Finder = .Range("CJ:CJ").Find(TheItem, LookAt:=xlWhole)
        Do Untill Finder Is Nothing Then
            MsgBox ("Item not found!")
        Exit Sub
        End If 
    With Sheets("EC Normal Run")
        Finder.EntireRow.Copy .Range("A" & lrowEC + 1)
        .Select 
    End With
    Set Finder = .FindNext(after:=Finder)
   Loop                                                                                                         End With

Comment: I ve tried many diff ways loops and so on but it is not working. Thanks a lot in advance.

Comment: I added an edit showing how to retrieve multiple records using `FindNext`. Let me know if you need any more help. It would probably be easier to simply loop through the range of cells instead of using FindNext. I prefer using Find when it's 1 item, but looping when I'm looking for multiple items for simplicity sake. That being said, the updated code should work.

Comment: Sorry for my late reply! Thanks a lot it works perfectly!